# Why do I get a Parse error? (Python)

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, parse-error

I am getting a Parse error >> ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 1.
I need to parse a JSON file to KML file!
Please keep note that this is not all of my code!

If somebody could just help me right there where I did something wrong?
I am also getting an error (ValueError: time data "'2013-07-26T22:34:56Z'" does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ') when I am changing the "s" to an "r" right after `%(timestampMs)` in this code:

```
"<TimeStamp><when>%(timestampMs)s</when></TimeStamp>"
```

This is the content of the JSON file (just a few) Ignore the "kind" type:

```
{
  "data" :{
    "items" :[{
      "kind" : "latitude#location",
      "timestampMs" : "1374870896803",
      "latitude" : 34.9482949,
      "longitude" : -85.3245474,
      "accuracy" : 2149
    }]
  }
}
```

This is the Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "..\mapPlot.py", line 106, in <module>
  DrawMapData(GetKmlFiles(),ImageData[0], "Location History.png", 
  ImageData[1], ImageData[2], ImageData[3], 
  ImageData[4],ImageData[5],ImageData[6])
  File "..\mapPlot.py", line 21, in GetKmlFiles
  KmlData.append(ReadKmlFile(dirname, filename))
  File "..\mapPlot.py", line 38, in ReadKmlFile
  latlist.append(float(ET.fromstring(line)[0].text.split(',')[0]))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1300, in XML
  parser.feed(text)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1642, in feed
  self._raiseerror(v)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1506, in _raiseerror
  raise err
```

Here is my code for parsing JSON to KML:

```
import json
import os, time, math
from datetime import datetime
from time import mktime
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw


def parse_json_data_to_kml_file():
   kml_file = open('location.kml', "w")

  json_file = open('LocationHistory.json')
  json_string = json_file.read()
  json_data = json.loads(json_string)

  locations = json_data["data"]["items"]

  placemark = ["<Placemark>",
               "<TimeStamp><when>%(timestampMs)s</when></TimeStamp>",
               "<ExtendedData>",
               "<Data name=\"accuracy\">",
               "<value>%(accuracy)r</value>]",
               "</Data>",
               "</ExtendedData><Point><coordinates>%(longitude)r, %
               (latitude)r</coordinates></Point>",
               "</Placemark>"]

               placemark = "\n".join(placemark)

   for location in locations:
       location['timestampMs'] = 
       datetime.fromtimestamp(int(location.get("timestampMs"))/1000)
       .strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")

       temp = placemark % location
       kml_file.write("\n" + temp + "\n")


   kml_file.close()
   json_file.close()

parse_json_data_to_kml_file()
```

Comment: Show us only the code that produces the error and the input that cannot be parsed.

Comment: Please look at my question now? I changed something! @timgeb

Comment: It's still a wall of code.

Comment: Please look at it now? Haha... @timgeb

Comment: Ok, now give us the full traceback and the content of the json you are trying to parse.

Comment: Because with `r` it will include the single quotes. Why do you want that?

Comment: It should be fine now! :) @timgeb

Comment: "This is the content of the JSON file " => is this REALLY the CONTENT of your json file ? When you open it with a text editor ?

Comment: Yes! @brunodesthuilliers

Comment: @CarelSmit you edited the json snippet after I asked this question.

Comment: Until you post the traceback, no one will be able to help you.

Comment: I realised it before I answered your question, so I changed it then I answered your question! Sorry for this! :) @brunodesthuilliers

Comment: How do I post a traceback? @brunodesthuilliers

Comment: How do you post text ? Or code ? How did you post your question ? You have an error due to an exception, so you do have the whole traceback just before the error message. You copy it, edit your post and paste it into your post.

Comment: I added the Traceback! @brunodesthuilliers

Comment: Your json here has a space as the very first character. Make sure you don't have that in your file that would explain `(invalid token): line 1, column 1.`

Comment: It did nothing? :) @cricket_007

Comment: Make your json here in the question complete, please. Only put one object in the items array, then close the array and close the json objects, please

Comment: It is complete now! @cricket_007

Comment: Ok now you've posted the traceback can you please take one minute to actually **read** it ? Your parsing error is not with the json files but with XML parsing of the produced KML files, in a totally unrelated part of the code.

Comment: I see! I have just fixed it! And my program run smoothly!